# Block Outgoing sftp but not incoming sftp to Machine

Tags: 14.04, security, sftp

Is there a way of blocking file transfer from a Linux Machine to any other machine (could be either by FTP or SFTP), while allowing file uploads from other machines to Linux machine? This is to safeguard against data theft.

Comment: Hi @Narsihma Reddy, wellcome to ask.ubuntu, it is not clear precisely what your question is. What is your question?

Comment: I have rephrased the question. @Tshilidzi

Comment: Looking good now (i think)

Comment: You can't protect against data theft from the inside with network rules. Period. People will just find different network services to transmit data because that's what all network communication is for. I can show you software that tunnels arbitrary TCP connections over DNS requests. …Or they'll bring a USB drive and copy the data onto it. Your best bet against data theft from the inside is to block *all* network communication with the outside and search your employees for storage media every time they leave the facilities.